# Prove that the sum of $\dim(\ker(T- c_1\operatorname{Id})) + \cdots + \dim(\ker(T-c_h\operatorname{Id}) \leq \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T))$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vectorial space and $T$ is a linear transformation.
Assume you have $k$ (distinct) non-zero eigenvalues: $c_1, c_2, \dots,c_k$. If
$d_r = \dim(\ker(T-c_r\operatorname{Id})$ , prove that $d_1 + \cdots + d_k \leq \dim\operatorname{Im}T$

---

To prove this I tried this: if $v$ belongs to $\ker(T-c_r.\operatorname{Id})$, then $(T-c_r .\operatorname{Id})$ (v) = 0,

$T(v) - c_r . Id(v) = 0.$ (Is that correct? I´m not sure). So, $T(v) = c_r .\operatorname{Id}(v)= c_r.v$, so $c_r$ is an eigenvalue.

To be honest, I think I'm having a hard time figuring out where to go to prove it (how the $\dim\operatorname{Im}T$ is related to the other dimensions), help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well this may be a hint: Let $d_0$ be $\dim\ker (T)$, then you are by the R/N Thm trying to prove that $d_0+d_1+\dots+d_k\leqslant \dim V$. You ought to be able to prove that.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks, it was a really good hint! From that point, I can use the rank-nullity theorem and prove the statement. The only thing that left me in doubt: to use "$d_0 + d_1 + ...+ dk \leq dimV$, I should prove it before, right? (Just to be sure)

Comment: Yes, prove that inequality. [You've probably done so by now.] Personally I would get it as a corollary of the Chinese Remainder Theorem: if $f,g$are coprime polynomials then $\ker f(T)g(T)=\ker f(T)\oplus \ker g(T)$.